# facebook PHP error 102, Session key invalid or no longer valid

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to make a simple login by using PHP and Facebook. THe problem is that I've this result when It's supposed to be shown the "iframe","popup" or "page" (none of them are working)

```
API Error Code: 102
API Error Description: Session key invalid or no longer valid
Error Message: Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key
```

The code I'm using for now is this:

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'CODE1',
    'secret' => 'CODE2',
    'cookie' => true
);

$params = array(
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://domain.dev',
    'display'=>'iframe'
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    //something
} else {
    $user = null;
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);    
    //redirect to loginURL                  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
if (!(isset($_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://domain.dev',
        'display' => 'popup',
        'scope' => 'user_photos'
            ));
    echo $loginUrl;
```

For more reference you can use this :

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html

Comment: only worked once!, why!?!, now It's happening the same, look that is not very solid....I don't know.

Comment: try to put code in `try-catch` block and check what exception it prints

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot, I think was later my Jquery, with your modification I forgot something in the JS I use to fire everything